# Change Bundle identifier in IOS App update

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

I am facing a issues in submitting my app in app store. I have an app with `bundle identifier` `com.xxx.yyy` and the app name is `AppOne`, meanwhile I am developing another app with `bundle identifier` `com.aaa.zzz` and name `AppTwo`. Now I want my app `AppTwo` to be released as a update for `AppOne`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: change the bundle identifier and bundle display name to the app u want in Info.plist fileand ur problem is solved

Comment: How to change the bundle display name?.
Are u sure if we change the bundle identifier and display name of new app to the name in old app it will work ?

Comment: If you don't find out "Bundle display name" in info.plist, you should add a new row with key name "Bundle display name" and add desired name as value of the key.
@muku is absolutely right. Yes, it will work if you change bundle identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**Below i have added the screenshot which shows both the fields**

Bundle Display Name:-Add your app name

Bundle Identifier:-add your identifier